# Why isn't the edit history visible on normal questions?

Tags: support, revisions-list, edits

In community wiki type questions we have an option to view the revision history of the question asked. But why isn't this available for normal questions?

There is no way for me to see what has actually been edited in my question. I do know about the Rollback option, but what is the use of allowing me to rollback without even giving the option to view the modification history?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always view the history: When it says "Edited 1 hour ago" below the question, the "1 hour ago" part is a [link to the revision list](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1361568/list).

Comment: thanks balpha.. my mistake.. :( dint see the link...